# Where is nginx configuration in centos?

Tags: nginx, centos, gitlab

I installed GitLab in centos 7 and now I'm trying to run GitLab on https. According to [this article](http://samwize.com/2014/07/24/how-to-setup-git-server-gitlab-with-ssl/) I need to change some configuration directives in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/gitlab` But there is no such file in my system. Could you please tell me where the config file is located in my case? I used [this method](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#centos7) to install the gitlab.

Comment: That's because you don't have `nginx` installed normally. You have the bundled `gitlab-ce` version of `nginx`. Run `rpm -ql gitlab-ce | grep nginx` and you'll find it.

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS Nginx configuration should be under /etc/nginx/ and for individual blocks it should be under /etc/nginx/conf.d